# When a TrustManagerFactory is not a TrustManagerFactory (Java)

Tags: java, security, ssl, junit, pkix

I am trying to add some additional JUnit test to an existing App-Server (TomCat) product. I have run into an issue with the (existing and fielded) custom TrustManager. This thing works fine in production, but during JUnit, gives exception.

The customized TrustManager merely loads a keystore from a path, and implicitly trusts our own public certs. For some reason, using this in JUnits causes an exception on the following line:

```
TrustManagerFactory tmFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("PKIX");
```

Exception:

```
java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException:  class configured for TrustManagerFactory: com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.TrustManagerFactoryImpl$PKIXFactory not a TrustManagerFactory
```

This exception takes place regardless of what Provider/Algorithm combinations are used ("SunX509", .getDefaultAlgorithm(), et al.).

Any insight will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: AFAICT, Idea is using %JAVA_HOME%, which resolves to:  
`java version "1.6.0_23"` 
`Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_23-b05)`  
`Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 19.0-b09, mixed mode)`

Comment: It looks like JUnit has somehow messed up the security providers configuration.

Comment: If you mean the Providers, they seem OK (I can peruse them and find PKIX under both BC and SunX509, etc) . . . . which is strange.

Comment: Do you by any chance have the old JSSE jar file from 1.3 days installed somewhere on the CLASSPATH where JUnit can see it but production can't? If so, remove it.

Comment: Not as far as I can tell. 

Strange bit is:  I moved the SSL init function into another class and the issue with the TrustManager went away. 

No idea of why. >_<

Comment: A perfect example of ambiguous java exception messages.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Well, looks like PowerMock messes up with SSL issues and thus, you run into loading a wrong factory. The solution for that is to use an annotation on the test class:

```
@PowerMockIgnore("javax.net.ssl.*")
```

this is taken from https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/powermock/v4nreP2AnOQ

Comment: Perfect :) Thanks!